# Device Unable to Boot, Error - mdtp image is corrupted

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, fastboot

I am trying to install a custom on my Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite (first timer). However, I am facing a difficulty as my phone is showing me the error "Device Unable to Boot, Error - mdtp image is corrupted".

System I am using: Linux Mint 20.2

Things I did:

1. Downloaded TWRP and ROM file.
2. Unlocked the bootloader.
3. Booted into TWRP by running "fastboot boot twrp*.img" in the terminal when fast screen appears on my phone.
   [I tried out this command "fastboot flash recovery twrp*.img" before running the above command, but failed and showed remote: partition table doesn't exist]

[So, it worked out well. However, I forgot to create backups]

4. Wiped "Dalvik/ART Cache", Data, System, Internal Storage.
5. Went to "install" and tried to flash the zip file of the ROM. However, it gave an error. [Probably, error 7, don't know what that mean]
6. Then, tried to reboot and carry out the same process from the step 3, it gave me the error and I am stuck.

Now, I cannot do anything. Can you please help me out.

Thank You.

Comment: after install error 7 *'adb pull /tmp/recovery.log'*

Comment: @alecxs, I have tried the above command, but, getting this error message: "adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found".

Comment: use **official** [TWRP](https://twrp.me/xiaomi/xiaomimia2lite.html) (have double checked `adb` *will* work)

Comment: Yes, I am using the official TWRP, but not working...

Comment: *'adb kill-server'* and re-plug cable until you can see it on *'adb devices'*

Comment: if MicroSD Card is working you can copy *recovery.log* from [GUI](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kijyw79g0lerap8/recovery_log.png?dl=0&raw=1). please upload content pastebin.com

Answer (score 0):

flash vbmeta (if your device has verified boot) and disable verified boot before flashing custom recovery by the following command.

`fastboot --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img`

(ofc get vbmeta img for ur device yourself)

then flash recovery using the following command

`fastboot flash recovery <recovery file name.img`

then try flashing rom, if still fails, flash vendor partition in twrp before flashing rom

Comment: How does this fix error 7 in TWRP while flashing ROM *"Updater process ended with ERROR: 7 Error installing zip file"*?